# Python list pop method and keep a copy of the original list

Tags: python, list, python-3.6

I can't quite understand this behavior, but why in `python3` the `list.pop()` method removes the object from the list as well as the copied list, what if I'd like to have the copy as the reference. MWE:

```
>>> a =['1','2','3']
>>> a
['1', '2', '3']
>>> b=a
>>> b.pop(0)
'1'
>>> b
['2', '3']
>>> a
['2', '3']
```

Comment: `b=a` pass reference.To get a new list, use `b=a.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

The assignment of list `a` to `b` does not make a copy; they are still pointing to the same underlying list object.

If you want to make a full copy of the list you can just use slice notation to copy the full list:

```
>>> a =['1','2','3']
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b.pop(0)
'1'
>>> b
['2', '3']
>>> a
['1','2','3']
```

Or more generally, see the [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module

Comment: Interesting. However, this behavior does not happen when we modify the original list, say `a+1`. Does it relate to `pop()` or is it a general Python behavior?

Comment: @Amir: The behavior *does* happen in general when you modify the original (only) list. `a+1` is invalid for a list, but any actual modification would show up through both variables.

Comment: It's general Python behavior for mutable objects -- the same would happen if you were to modify the original list, say with with `a.append('4')`.   Strings and ints are immutable and thus wouldn't exhibit this same behavior